# Drop down menu not is working

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I would like to seek your help in my program. My menu bar was working a while ago before someone here helped me fix the problem in the links in my content file.

The code i removed from style2.css is z-index:1; from the #content css. doing this made the links inside the content div work. however, removing that line of code did something to my code.

here is a link to what happened and notice the drop down for our product and suggestion not working. I am sure it is somewhere in the css file, but i find it hard to search where.

http://jsfiddle.net/misaki03/9nw3zg4p/

here is the html file

```
<body>
<div id="container"> <!--wrapper-->
    <header id="header">
        <div id="menu" class="menu"> <!--navMenu-->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" > HOME </a></li>
                <li>OUR PRODUCT
                <ul> 
                    <li><a href="#" > PRODUCT OVERVIEW</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" > USAGE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" > PRODUCT REVIEWS </a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li> SUGGESTIONS 
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" > TIPS and IDEAS </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" > RECIPES </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" > SEND US YOUR IDEAS </a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" > ABOUT US </a> </li>
                <li><a href="#" > CONTACT US </a> </li>
            </ul> 
            <br class="clearFloat" />
        </div>
</header>

<section id="content">
    <div class="reviews" id="reviews">
    <center>
    <table style="width:700px;">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" id="overview"> <h2> - PRODUCT REVIEW - </h2> <br />  <h5>Our customers love us </h5> </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" > <img src="images/reviewID.jpg" /> </td>
            <td> <h3> Big Al 5000 </h3></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <p>There are some friends of mine who have a catering business that deals with private events, and they have had to make hemp/marijuana-based foods for their clients. They used cheesecloth for certain things like butter making, tea and even separating the plant from seeds. Let's just say it definitely works well for those purposes. I am not saying you should condone it, but it is an emerging culinary trade. The more it becomes legal, the more you will see this in even fine dining restaurants.</p></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"> <img src="images/reviewID.jpg" /> </td>
            <td> <h3> Ari </h3></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <p>I love cheese, but it is getting quite expensive these days. I have found myself doing a lot more DIY projects, and now I can say I have successfully made my own cheese. Sharp cheddar to be exact. It may not have been the absolute best cheese I ever had, but it was very, very good cheese. Definitely going to be making more now that I see how fulfilling it is. Might actually get even better at it. Wish me luck!</p></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"> <img src="images/reviewID.jpg" /> </td>
            <td> <h3> Miles </h3></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <p>TI saw something on Pinterest that showed babies in what looked like swaddling cloths. I had to look into it a bit, and I saw that it was actually cheesecloth that was being used. They are the cutest baby photos ever! I looked around online to see if there was any specific kind I had to get, and then I noticed that this one mentioned it was good for use in photography. I like it when my decisions are made for me (ha ha). I have now used this cloth for other things also. I just cut a piece off here and there and get a wash rag or dust rag or whatever. It is pretty good for just about anything you would use a rag for.</p></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"> <img src="images/reviewID.jpg" /> </td>
            <td> <h3> Neil T </h3></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <p>I used it as halloween decorations then I used it for my turkey on Thanksgiving. I also used it as a seed stopper for my lemons as I saw once in a restaurant. Made calamari for a dinner and didn't get seeds in it. This is a good quality cloth. I am going to test it out on my Christmas ham, because I have plenty left over.</p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </center>
    </div>

</section>

<footer id="footer">
    <div id="fmenu" class="fmenu">
        <p>©2015 copyright    |   Perfect Holiday All Rights Reserved</p>
        <ul class="social_icons">
            <li class="social">
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/ourperfectholiday" target="_blank">
                    <img src="images/fb.png" /> </a></li>
            <li class="social">
                <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/OPerfectHoliday/" target="_blank">
                    <img src="images/pin.png" /> </a></li>
            <li class="social">
                <a href="https://instagram.com/perfectholiday.cheesecloth/" target="_blank">
                    <img src="images/insta.png" /> </a></li>
        </ul>
</footer>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

And the css file

```
.fmenu, .push{
    height: 4em;
    clear:both;
}

/*ends here */

body {
    background: url(images/cheeseclothBG.jpg)no-repeat center center fixed;
    font-family: Avenir !important;
    font-size: 12pt;
    line-height: 20px;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;

}
#header {
    background: url(images/header.jpg) no-repeat;
    min-height: 270px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: 100%;
}
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -101px;
    background: #fff;

    position:relative;
}


#img {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #0000ff;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
#img img{
    display: inline;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

#desc{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 5px;
}


#container {
    width: 826px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #ccc;
}

#menu{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#menu ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0; 
    line-height:30px;
    margin-left:35px;
    margin-top: 139px;
}

#menu li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background:#fff;
}

#menu ul li a{
    text-align:center;
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    height:30px;
    width:150px;
    display:block;
    color:#000;
    margin-left:10px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #999;
}

#menu ul li{
    text-align:center;
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    height:30px;
    width:150px;
    display:block;
    color:#000;

    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #999;
}

#menu ul li ul li a{
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:0px;


}

#menu ul li ul{
    margin-top:-5px;
}

#menu ul li ul li{
    margin-top:-2px;
    margin-left:-35px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:3px;
}
#menu ul ul{
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    top:32px;
    z-index:10px;

}

#menu ul li:hover ul{
    visibility:visible;
}

/*******************************/
#menu li:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;

}

#menu ul li:hover ul li a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#fa9a2a;

}

#menu a:hover{
    color:#fa9a2a;
}

#menu ul li:hover {
    color:#fa9a2a;
}



.clearFloat{
    clear:both;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}

#content p {
    margin: 30px 30px;
}

#footer {
    background: url(images/footer.jpg);
    min-height: 146px;
    background-size: 100%;
    clear: both;

}
#fmenu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 120px;
    padding-top: 19px;
}
#fmenu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#fmenu ul li a {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1px 14px 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    color: #000000;
}

#fmenu p {
    /**margin-top: 120px;
    margin-left: 480px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 310px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #000;
    text-align: right;**/

    width:70%;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size: 8pt;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:10px;
    display:inline-flex;
    margin-top: 110px;
}

#fmenu img{
    width:36px;
    height:36px;
}
#fmenu ul.social_icons, li.social {
    margin-top:40px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    max-width:25%;
    list-style: none;
    float:right;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

#mainTxt p{
    margin: 40px 100px;
}

#overview h2{
    font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #9d9b9b;
    font-size: 26px;

}
#overview h1{
    font-family: Impact, !important;
    font-size: 46px;
}
#overview h4{
    font-family: Gabriola, !important;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #e2705a;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
#overview h3{
    font-family: Sacramento, !important;
    font-size: 36px;
        margin-top: -20px;
}

#overview h5{
    font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-top: -20px;

}

#reviews table th td{
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#reviews h5{
    font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align:center;
}

#reviews h2{
    font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #9d9b9b;
    font-size: 26px;
}
 #reviews h3{
     font-family: Sacramento, !important;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight:bold;
 }

#usage h1{
    font-family: Cookie, !important;
    font-size: 46px;
    float:left;
}
#usage img{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}

#about p{
    font-family: Georgia, !important;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: justify;
}

#about2 p{
    font-family: Avenir, !important;
    font-size: 16px;
    width:600px;
}

#about2 ul{
    width:600px;
}

#about2 li{
    font-family: Avenir, !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    width:600px;
    text-align: left;
}

#recipe h2{
    font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #9d9b9b;
    font-size: 26px;

}
#recipe h1{
    font-family: Gabriola, !important;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #e2705a;

}

#recipe h4{
    font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: -20px;

}

#recipe h5{
    font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    color: red;

}

#recipe p{
    margin-top: -20px;

}
#tips h2{
    font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #9d9b9b;
    font-size: 26px;

}
#tips h1{
    font-family: Gabriola, !important;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #e2705a;
}

#tips h4{
    font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
#tips h5{
    font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    color: red;
}

#tips p{
    margin-top: -20px;
}
#tips h6{
    font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: Start with your syntax, just from a glance, you are closing the </footer> before closing the nested <div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now it works with below code but there is lot of scope for improvement in this code structure wise and with css also

i have used z-index to show hide the drop down list instead of visibility property.

corrected z-index declaration z-indexes can not be declared in pixels you can write simply as eg: z-index : 1 ;

```css
/* sticky footer codes */

.fmenu,
.push {
  height: 4em;
  clear: both;
}
/*ends here */

body {
  background: url(images/cheeseclothBG.jpg)no-repeat center center fixed;
  font-family: Avenir !important;
  font-size: 12pt;
  line-height: 20px;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
#header {
  background: url(images/header.jpg) no-repeat;
  min-height: 270px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: 100%;
}
#content {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -101px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
#img {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #0000ff;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
#img img {
  display: inline;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
#desc {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 5px;
}
#container {
  width: 826px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #ccc;
}
#menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 139px;
}
#menu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}
#menu ul li a {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #999;
}
#menu ul li {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #999;
}
#menu ul li ul li a {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
#menu ul li ul {
  margin-top: -5px;
}
#menu ul li ul li {
  margin-top: -2px;
  margin-left: -35px;
  position: relative;
}
#menu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul {
  z-index: 1;
}
/*******************************/

#menu li:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #fa9a2a;
}
#menu a:hover {
  color: #fa9a2a;
}
#menu ul li:hover {
  color: #fa9a2a;
}
.clearFloat {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#content p {
  margin: 30px 30px;
}
#footer {
  background: url(images/footer.jpg);
  min-height: 146px;
  background-size: 100%;
  clear: both;
}
#fmenu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 120px;
  padding-top: 19px;
}
#fmenu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#fmenu ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1px 14px 0;
  margin-top: 0px;
  color: #000000;
}
#fmenu p {
  /**margin-top: 120px;
 margin-left: 480px;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 310px;
 font-size: 11px;
 color: #000;
 text-align: right;**/
  width: 70%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 8pt;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-top: 110px;
}
#fmenu img {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}
#fmenu ul.social_icons,
li.social {
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  max-width: 25%;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
#mainTxt p {
  margin: 40px 100px;
}
#overview h2 {
  font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #9d9b9b;
  font-size: 26px;
}
#overview h1 {
  font-family: Impact, !important;
  font-size: 46px;
}
#overview h4 {
  font-family: Gabriola, !important;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #e2705a;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
#overview h3 {
  font-family: Sacramento, !important;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
#overview h5 {
  font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
#reviews table th td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#reviews h5 {
  font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}
#reviews h2 {
  font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #9d9b9b;
  font-size: 26px;
}
#reviews h3 {
  font-family: Sacramento, !important;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#usage h1 {
  font-family: Cookie, !important;
  font-size: 46px;
  float: left;
}
#usage img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
#about p {
  font-family: Georgia, !important;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: justify;
}
#about2 p {
  font-family: Avenir, !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 600px;
}
#about2 ul {
  width: 600px;
}
#about2 li {
  font-family: Avenir, !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 600px;
  text-align: left;
}
#recipe h2 {
  font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #9d9b9b;
  font-size: 26px;
}
#recipe h1 {
  font-family: Gabriola, !important;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #e2705a;
}
#recipe h4 {
  font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
#recipe h5 {
  font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  color: red;
}
#recipe p {
  margin-top: -20px;
}
#tips h2 {
  font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #9d9b9b;
  font-size: 26px;
}
#tips h1 {
  font-family: Gabriola, !important;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #e2705a;
}
#tips h4 {
  font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
#tips h5 {
  font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  color: red;
}
#tips p {
  margin-top: -20px;
}
#tips h6 {
  font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <!--wrapper-->
    <header id="header">
      <div id="menu" class="menu">
        <!--navMenu-->
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"> HOME </a>
          </li>
          <li>OUR PRODUCT
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#"> PRODUCT OVERVIEW</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"> USAGE</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"> PRODUCT REVIEWS </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>SUGGESTIONS
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#"> TIPS and IDEAS </a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"> RECIPES </a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"> SEND US YOUR IDEAS </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"> ABOUT US </a> 
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"> CONTACT US </a> 
          </li>
        </ul>
        <br class="clearFloat" />
      </div>
    </header>

    <section id="content">
      <div class="reviews" id="reviews">
        <center>
          <table style="width:700px;">
            <tr>
              <th colspan="2" id="overview">
                <h2> - PRODUCT REVIEW - </h2> 
                <br />
                <h5>Our customers love us </h5> 
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td rowspan="2">
                <img src="images/reviewID.jpg" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <h3> Big Al 5000 </h3>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>There are some friends of mine who have a catering business that deals with private events, and they have had to make hemp/marijuana-based foods for their clients. They used cheesecloth for certain things like butter making, tea and even
                  separating the plant from seeds. Let's just say it definitely works well for those purposes. I am not saying you should condone it, but it is an emerging culinary trade. The more it becomes legal, the more you will see this in even fine
                  dining restaurants.</p>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td rowspan="2">
                <img src="images/reviewID.jpg" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <h3> Ari </h3>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>I love cheese, but it is getting quite expensive these days. I have found myself doing a lot more DIY projects, and now I can say I have successfully made my own cheese. Sharp cheddar to be exact. It may not have been the absolute best
                  cheese I ever had, but it was very, very good cheese. Definitely going to be making more now that I see how fulfilling it is. Might actually get even better at it. Wish me luck!</p>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td rowspan="2">
                <img src="images/reviewID.jpg" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <h3> Miles </h3>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>TI saw something on Pinterest that showed babies in what looked like swaddling cloths. I had to look into it a bit, and I saw that it was actually cheesecloth that was being used. They are the cutest baby photos ever! I looked around online
                  to see if there was any specific kind I had to get, and then I noticed that this one mentioned it was good for use in photography. I like it when my decisions are made for me (ha ha). I have now used this cloth for other things also.
                  I just cut a piece off here and there and get a wash rag or dust rag or whatever. It is pretty good for just about anything you would use a rag for.</p>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td rowspan="2">
                <img src="images/reviewID.jpg" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <h3> Neil T </h3>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>I used it as halloween decorations then I used it for my turkey on Thanksgiving. I also used it as a seed stopper for my lemons as I saw once in a restaurant. Made calamari for a dinner and didn't get seeds in it. This is a good quality
                  cloth. I am going to test it out on my Christmas ham, because I have plenty left over.</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </center>
      </div>

    </section>

    <footer id="footer">
      <div id="fmenu" class="fmenu">
        <p>©2015 copyright | Perfect Holiday All Rights Reserved</p>
        <ul class="social_icons">
          <li class="social">
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/ourperfectholiday" target="_blank">
              <img src="images/fb.png" />
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="social">
            <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/OPerfectHoliday/" target="_blank">
              <img src="images/pin.png" />
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="social">
            <a href="https://instagram.com/perfectholiday.cheesecloth/" target="_blank">
              <img src="images/insta.png" />
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </footer>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: hi i tried your code and it did the job. i just can't find what made the error. is it just the z-index code having px in its value? just wanna make sure i avoid that next time. sorry if the code was messy as well. still relearning how to code. its been a long time since i made one.

Answer (score 2):

buddy very messy code and many unwanted things!
and about issue: You missed two things:

```
#menu ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    top:32px;
    z-index:10; /* you gave it px unit*/
}
#menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block; /* you given display none, but didn't gave block on li hover*/
    visibility:visible;
}
/**
```

```css
/* sticky footer codes */

.fmenu,
.push {
  height: 4em;
  clear: both;
}
/*ends here */

body {
  background: url(images/cheeseclothBG.jpg)no-repeat center center fixed;
  font-family: Avenir !important;
  font-size: 12pt;
  line-height: 20px;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
#header {
  background: url(images/header.jpg) no-repeat;
  min-height: 270px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: 100%;
}
#content {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -101px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
#img {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #0000ff;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
#img img {
  display: inline;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
#desc {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 5px;
}
#container {
  width: 826px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #ccc;
}
#menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 139px;
}
#menu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}
#menu ul li a {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #999;
}
#menu ul li {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #999;
}
#menu ul li ul li a {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
#menu ul li ul {
  margin-top: -5px;
  display: none;
}
#menu ul li ul li {
  margin-top: -2px;
  margin-left: -35px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3px;
}
#menu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 32px;
  z-index: 10;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
}
/*******************************/

#menu li:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #fa9a2a;
}
#menu a:hover {
  color: #fa9a2a;
}
#menu ul li:hover {
  color: #fa9a2a;
}
.clearFloat {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#content p {
  margin: 30px 30px;
}
#footer {
  background: url(images/footer.jpg);
  min-height: 146px;
  background-size: 100%;
  clear: both;
}
#fmenu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 120px;
  padding-top: 19px;
}
#fmenu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#fmenu ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1px 14px 0;
  margin-top: 0px;
  color: #000000;
}
#fmenu p {
  /**margin-top: 120px;
    margin-left: 480px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 310px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #000;
    text-align: right;**/
  width: 70%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 8pt;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-top: 110px;
}
#fmenu img {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}
#fmenu ul.social_icons,
li.social {
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  max-width: 25%;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
#mainTxt p {
  margin: 40px 100px;
}
#overview h2 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed' !important;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #9d9b9b;
  font-size: 26px;
}
#overview h1 {
  font-family: Impact, !important;
  font-size: 46px;
}
#overview h4 {
  font-family: Gabriola, !important;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #e2705a;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
#overview h3 {
  font-family: Sacramento, !important;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
#overview h5 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed' !important;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
#reviews table th td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#reviews h5 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed' !important;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}
#reviews h2 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed' !important;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #9d9b9b;
  font-size: 26px;
}
#reviews h3 {
  font-family: Sacramento, !important;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#usage h1 {
  font-family: Cookie, !important;
  font-size: 46px;
  float: left;
}
#usage img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
#about p {
  font-family: Georgia, !important;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: justify;
}
#about2 p {
  font-family: Avenir, !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 600px;
}
#about2 ul {
  width: 600px;
}
#about2 li {
  font-family: Avenir, !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 600px;
  text-align: left;
}
#recipe h2 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed' !important;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #9d9b9b;
  font-size: 26px;
}
#recipe h1 {
  font-family: Gabriola, !important;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #e2705a;
}
#recipe h4 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed' !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
#recipe h5 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed' !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  color: red;
}
#recipe p {
  margin-top: -20px;
}
#tips h2 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed' !important;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #9d9b9b;
  font-size: 26px;
}
#tips h1 {
  font-family: Gabriola, !important;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #e2705a;
}
#tips h4 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed' !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
#tips h5 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed' !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  color: red;
}
#tips p {
  margin-top: -20px;
}
#tips h6 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed' !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <!--wrapper-->
  <header id="header">
    <div id="menu" class="menu">
      <!--navMenu-->
      <ul class="ddmenu">
        <li><a href="#"> HOME </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">OUR PRODUCT</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> PRODUCT OVERVIEW</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"> USAGE</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"> PRODUCT REVIEWS </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">SUGGESTIONS</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> TIPS and IDEAS </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"> RECIPES </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"> SEND US YOUR IDEAS </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> ABOUT US </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> CONTACT US </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <br class="clearFloat" />
    </div>
  </header>
  <section id="content">
    <div class="reviews" id="reviews">
      <center>
        <table style="width:700px;">
          <tr>
            <th colspan="2" id="overview">
              <h2> - PRODUCT REVIEW - </h2>
              <br />
              <h5>Our customers love us </h5>
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">
              <img src="images/reviewID.jpg" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <h3> Big Al 5000 </h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p>There are some friends of mine who have a catering business that deals with private events, and they have had to make hemp/marijuana-based foods for their clients. They used cheesecloth for certain things like butter making, tea and even
                separating the plant from seeds. Let's just say it definitely works well for those purposes. I am not saying you should condone it, but it is an emerging culinary trade. The more it becomes legal, the more you will see this in even fine
                dining restaurants.</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">
              <img src="images/reviewID.jpg" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <h3> Ari </h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p>I love cheese, but it is getting quite expensive these days. I have found myself doing a lot more DIY projects, and now I can say I have successfully made my own cheese. Sharp cheddar to be exact. It may not have been the absolute best cheese
                I ever had, but it was very, very good cheese. Definitely going to be making more now that I see how fulfilling it is. Might actually get even better at it. Wish me luck!</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">
              <img src="images/reviewID.jpg" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <h3> Miles </h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p>TI saw something on Pinterest that showed babies in what looked like swaddling cloths. I had to look into it a bit, and I saw that it was actually cheesecloth that was being used. They are the cutest baby photos ever! I looked around online
                to see if there was any specific kind I had to get, and then I noticed that this one mentioned it was good for use in photography. I like it when my decisions are made for me (ha ha). I have now used this cloth for other things also. I
                just cut a piece off here and there and get a wash rag or dust rag or whatever. It is pretty good for just about anything you would use a rag for.</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">
              <img src="images/reviewID.jpg" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <h3> Neil T </h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p>I used it as halloween decorations then I used it for my turkey on Thanksgiving. I also used it as a seed stopper for my lemons as I saw once in a restaurant. Made calamari for a dinner and didn't get seeds in it. This is a good quality
                cloth. I am going to test it out on my Christmas ham, because I have plenty left over.</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </center>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer id="footer">
    <div id="fmenu" class="fmenu">
      <p>©2015 copyright | Perfect Holiday All Rights Reserved</p>
      <ul class="social_icons">
        <li class="social">
          <a href="http://www.facebook.com/ourperfectholiday" target="_blank">
            <img src="images/fb.png" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="social">
          <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/OPerfectHoliday/" target="_blank">
            <img src="images/pin.png" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="social">
          <a href="https://instagram.com/perfectholiday.cheesecloth/" target="_blank">
            <img src="images/insta.png" />
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi just remove px from this css rule because z-index value doesn't allow value with px

```css
#menu ul ul{
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    top:32px;
    z-index:10;

}
```

and here is the updated js fiddle

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nw3zg4p/1/)**

Comment: @MisaChan please check the answer and this thing was causing your problem dude